# ClassNotFoundException while running spring boot multi release jar with java 11

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

While trying to run the spring boot application (with multi release jar) against different versions of java [java 8 (default)  and java 11]

The project is running fine when ran with Java 8. However, upon running the application with java 11 getting ClassNotFoundException

The Project Structure:

[image]

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start.class>com.example.demo.DemoApplication</start.class>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.inq</groupId>
        <artifactId>touchsocial-stress-testing</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <toolchains>
                    <jdk>
                        <version>zulu-11</version>
                    </jdk>
                </toolchains>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>toolchain</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>8</release>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-java-11</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>11</release>
                        <compileSourceRoots>
                            <compileSourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</compileSourceRoot>
                        </compileSourceRoots>
                        <multiReleaseOutput>true</multiReleaseOutput>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${start.class}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

after adding the <start-class> mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69409550/9093334) the build is successful

But, on Running the jar on java 11 getting ClassNotFoundException

[image]

for java 8 (java_home), everything seems fine

[image]

*Note: For POC purpose the contents of both the DemoApplication.java is exactly the same*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Maven configuration is packaging your multi-release classes in the root of the jar. This means that they're loaded by the system class loader. The system class loader cannot see any of the dependencies packaged in `BOOT-INF/lib` so `SpringApplication` cannot be loaded.

You need to configure your app to package the multi-release classes beneath `BOOT-INF/classes`. One way to do that is to configure the compile task's output directory:

```
<execution>
    <id>compile-java-11</id>
    <phase>compile</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <release>11</release>
        <compileSourceRoots>
            <compileSourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</compileSourceRoot>
        </compileSourceRoots>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/BOOT-INF/classes/</outputDirectory>
        <multiReleaseOutput>true</multiReleaseOutput>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

If you do a clean build after making this change, the Java 11-specific class will now be packaged beneath `BOOT-INF/classes/META-INF/versions/11/`. As a result, it'll be loaded by Spring Boot's class loader and will be able to access classes from the jars packaged in `BOOT-INF/lib`.

This feels like something that Spring Boot's Maven plugin should take care of for you. I've opened https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28234.